# Error when running setup.py for cocos2d

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm following [this guide](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/manual/framework/native/v3/getting-started/how-to-run-cpp-tests-on-android/en) for cocos2d and having a hard time figuring out why I get an error. I'm on the "Use setup.py to configure your android development environment" section in the guide. Every time I run setup.py I get this:

```
Setting up cocos2d-x...
->Check environment variable COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT
  ->Search for environment variable COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT...
    ->COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT not found

  -> Add COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT environment variable...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 730, in <module>
    opts.ndk_root, opts.android_sdk_root, opts.ant_root)
  File "setup.py", line 687, in set_environment_variables
    self.set_console_root()
  File "setup.py", line 473, in set_console_root
    COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT, cocos_consle_root)
  File "setup.py", line 206, in _set_environment_variable
    ret = self._set_environment_variable_unix(key, value)
  File "setup.py", line 186, in _set_environment_variable_unix
    shutil.copy(self.file_used_for_setup, self.backup_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 119, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: You should post your code so that we can compare

Comment: which code do you mean? All I've done so far is install python and Apache ant. Do you mean the code from setup.py? If so, I never changed it after downloading cocos2d.

Comment: You said you were following a guide, but never stated how far into the guide you have got, the more information y can provide the better

Comment: Just added the section name.

Comment: be sure that path to your project or cocos2d-x does not contain any spaces or other "special" characters

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check if you set all environment variables from mentioned guide. Message COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT not found means that the environment variable is not visible or not set for current terminal session. Set environment vars and restart terminal and try run command again.